# Ocultar contenido excepto el que se encuentra chequeado

Tags: css3

Tengo el siguiente código HTML:

```html
<div id="contenedor">
 <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="opcion" checked="checked" />
 <label for="tab1">Tab1</label>
 <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="opcion" />
 <label for="tab2">Tab2</label>
 <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="opcion" />
 <label for="tab3">Tab3</label>
 <div id="contenido">
  <div id="contenido1">
   <p class="left"><img src="imagenes/una.jpg" alt="">Contenido 1 primer párrafo</p>
  <p class="left last"><img src="imagenes/dos.jpg" alt="">Contenido 1 segundo párrafo</p>
 </div>
  <div id="contenido2">
   <p>Contenido 2 primer párrafo</p>
  <p>Contenido 2 segundo párrafo</p>
 </div>
 <div id="contenido3">
   <p>Contenido 3</p>
       <ul>
           <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
           <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
           <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          </ul>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Y necesito ocultar todos los div con id "contenido(número)", y visualizar el contenido del que se encuentre chequeado.

Lo primero lo consigo con:

```css
#contenido {
 display: none;
}
```

Pero para mostrar el chequeado no consigo determinar la forma.

Esto no funciona.

```css
#contenedor input: checked #contenido {
 display: block;
}
```

No se puede usar JavaScript, ni editar el HTML. Lo cual me complica encontrar solución, lógicamente.

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: agrega el display: block !important;

Comment: Ya lo he agregado. La verdad, no entiendo tu comentario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo puedes conseguir usando sólo CSS, sin necesidad de JavaScript o cambios en tu HTML. La idea sería la siguiente:

- Todos los `div` dentro de `#contenido` están escondidos por defecto (con `display:none`)
- Cuando se seleciona una checkbox, se muestra el `div` asociado (con `display:block`).

Lo importante es encontrar el selector que funcione para el caso que quieres. Afortunadamente, por el modo en el que está estructurado tu HTML, se puede usar el operador de "hermano" `~` que te será de utilidad:

```css
/* todos los div de #contenido no se ven por defecto*/
#contenido > div {
  display:none;
}


/* reglas para los diferentes checkboxes y su div asociado */
#tab1:checked ~ #contenido #contenido1 {
  display:block;
}

#tab2:checked ~ #contenido #contenido2 {
  display:block;
}

#tab3:checked ~ #contenido #contenido3 {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="opcion" checked="checked" />
  <label for="tab1">Tab1</label>
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="opcion" />
  <label for="tab2">Tab2</label>
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="opcion" />
  <label for="tab3">Tab3</label>
  <div id="contenido">
    <div id="contenido1">
      <p class="left"><img src="imagenes/una.jpg" alt="">Contenido 1 primer párrafo</p>
      <p class="left last"><img src="imagenes/dos.jpg" alt="">Contenido 1 segundo párrafo</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contenido2">
      <p>Contenido 2 primer párrafo</p>
      <p>Contenido 2 segundo párrafo</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contenido3">
      <p>Contenido 3</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      </ul>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto. Este era el efecto que buscaba, pero no acertaba con los selectores.

Comment: Alvaro, tu respuesta me dejo impresionada, eres un genio, cada día hay algo nuevo por aprender.   Algún otro hack bajo la manga que nos puedas compartir?

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre usando javascript con los métodos hide y show.

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/pwf3n3rb/1/)

Comment: Gracias. Como le dije a Cristina, olvidé especificar que no puedo usar JavaScript ni tocar nada del HTML.

Comment: Encontré esta link a ver si te sirve algo https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/tpmAi

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
/*
$("#contenedor .tab").css("display","none");
$("#contenedor #contenido1").css("display","block");

$("#contenedor input[type=radio]").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  console.log("Click en" + id);
  //Oculto todos, para eso agrege la clase tab
  $("#contenedor .tab").css("display","none");
  //Muestro al que se le dio click, para esto le puse el atributo data-id a cada radio
  $("#contenedor #contenido"+id).css("display","block");
});
*/
```

```css
#contenido div{
  display: none;
}

#contenedor input[type=radio]:checked{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
 <input id="tab1" data-id="1" type="radio" name="opcion" checked="checked" />
 <label for="tab1">Tab1</label>
 <input id="tab2"  data-id="2" type="radio" name="opcion" />
 <label for="tab2">Tab2</label>
 <input id="tab3"  data-id="3" type="radio" name="opcion" />
 <label for="tab3">Tab3</label>
 <div id="contenido">
  <div id="contenido1" class="tab active">
   <p class="left"><img src="imagenes/una.jpg" alt="">Contenido 1 primer párrafo</p>
  <p class="left last"><img src="imagenes/dos.jpg" alt="">Contenido 1 segundo párrafo</p>
 </div>
  <div id="contenido2" class="tab">
   <p>Contenido 2 primer párrafo</p>
  <p>Contenido 2 segundo párrafo</p>
 </div>
 <div id="contenido3" class="tab">
   <p>Contenido 3</p>
       <ul>
           <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
           <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
           <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          </ul>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad, Saludos.

.... Con pur CSS.... dudo mucho que sea posible... :-S  no se me ocurre nada

Comment: Gracias. Se me olvidó especificar que ha de ser sólo con CSS, perdón.

Y sin editar el HTML. Por eso he recurrido a la comunidad, porque ya estoy absolutamente perdido.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaa ok..

Comment: @A.J. sin editar HTML te refieres sin poner clases??

Comment: Si. No se puede tocar absolutamente nada.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no me equivoco al decir que solo con css no se modificar propiedades de otros elementos que no sea el seleccionado. 
Estas intentando cambiar la propiedad display de un elemento "Hermano" con un id especifico, seleccionando un input tipo radio.
Si puedieras modificar el html quizá se pueda lograr con los pseudoSelectores :cheked y +
Saludos